# Generar Subcarpetas con Multer Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, multer

Tengo un servicio con Nodejs el cual recibe una foto mediante el metodo POST de una aplicacion android. Con Multer procesa la foto y la sube a un servidor en la ruta 'E:\Imagenes' pero me interesa guardar las fotos dependiendo del ID de cada una en carpetas diferentes.

Este es el codigo del Storage

```
storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: 'E:\imagenes/',
//El String deberia quedar algo asi 'E:\imagenes\'+id+'/'
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
  return crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    return cb(null, "" + (raw.toString('hex')) + (path.extname(file.originalname)));
  });
},
});
```

y este es el código para ejecutar Multer al recibir el POST

```
 app.post("/upload",multer({storage: storage}).single('upload'), function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body["Id"];
  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

El problema es que el "Id" lo recibo en el post, por ende se ejecuta después que el multer defina su Storage, entonces no puedo enviarle el id al string de la ubicación para generar una nueva carpeta. Se que para crear una nueva carpeta tengo que utilizar fs.mkdir.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Me base en la respuesta que dio el usuario **LinusU** en [github](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/322) en la cual comenta que el req.body no va a servir si estoy enviando como primer objeto la foto. Multer lo primero que hace es recibir lo que se le esta enviando y si la foto llega como primer parámetros este lo va a procesar de los primeros sin llegar a recibir los demas.

Por lo tanto modifique la estructura que tenia en el POST de android.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part("upload") RequestBody name,@Part("Id") RequestBody id,@Part("imagen") RequestBody imagebin
,@Part("comment") RequestBody comentario,@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

y deje como ultimo parámetro la imagen.

Luego de esto pude recibir el campo Id dentro del Storage del multer:

```
storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination:function(req, file, cb) {
    var carpeta = req.body["Id"]
    var ruta = `E:\imagenes/${carpeta}`
    fs1.mkdirsSync(ruta)
    cb(null, ruta);
},
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
console.log("-----Aqui estamos en el Storage Multer--------------")
console.log("       ")
  return crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    return cb(null, "" + (raw.toString('hex')) + (path.extname(file.originalname)));
  });
},
});
```

La parte del POST queda igual.

Espero la solución que obtuve le sirva a alguien mas.
Saludos.